# Access uploaded files react file input onChange

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have this code in jquery

```
//Js
$(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
  var files = Array.from(this.files)
  var fileName = files.map(f =>{return f.name}).join(", ")
  $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
});
```

```
//HTML 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple>
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

And am rewriting it in react

```
//React
<div class="custom-file">
  <input onChange={(this)=>{
       console.log(this);
       var files = Array.from(this.files)
       var fileName = files.map(f =>{return f.name}).join(", ")
       $(e).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
     }}
    type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple />
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

But I get log the `this` I get `undefined`, How can I go around this and why is does react function has no `this` in its function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on @Shankar Regmi's answer,  I figured out the to access file I can use `e.target.file`.  I so I edited mine react into.

```
//React
<div class="custom-file">
  <input style={{display:"block"}} onChange={(e)=>{
   var files = Array.from(e.target.files)
   var fileName = files.map(f =>{return f.name}).join(", ")
   $(e.target).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
   }} type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" multiple />
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file(Don't Upload 
   Videos)</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, You are trying to upload a file and output a label.

I created a sample here [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-drake-m4c68)

```js
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

 const FileComponent = () => {
   const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
   const [fileName, setFileName] = useState('')

   const handleChange = (event) => {
     const files = event.target.files;
     if(files.length) {
       const name = Array.from(files) .map((f) => { return f.name; }) .join(", ");
       setFiles(files);
       setFileName(name);
     }
   }


   return (
     <div>
       <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
       <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">{fileName || 'Choose File' }</label>
     </div>
   )
 }
```